# После введения запроса в поле поиска, осуществляется переход на новую страницу с названиями видео под этот запрос React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонента Feed, в ней лежит список видосов с базы данных, как реализовать то, чтоб после нажатия кнопки поиск я переходил на новую страницу с нужными видео по названию?

Часть кода feed:

```
                                        <form name="publish">
                                            <input id="search" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Поиск" />
                                            <button id="searchButton" type="submit"></button>
                                        </form>
```

Код Страницы результатов поиска:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Row, Col,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

import './SearchDisplay.scss';
import { MyContext } from '../../MyContext'
import Navigation from '../../layout/navigation/navigation';
import Header from '../../layout/header/Header';


// const CabinetContext = React.createContext()


const SearchDisplay = () => {

    let [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
    let [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const { isAuthorized, isFetching } = useContext(MyContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/user/my/favorites')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result =>{
            console.log(result)
            setVideos(videos= result )
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            setError(isFetching, error = e );
        });
        console.log('!!!',videos);
    }, [])




        if (isFetching) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        if (!isAuthorized) {
            return <Redirect to="/logreg1" />;
        }
        else
            return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <div  className="Max">

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={2}>
                            <Navigation key="navigation"/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <div className="Box">
                                <div className="VideoList">

                                    {Object.keys(videos).map(key => (
                                        <div className="VideoContainer">
                                            <a href={"./watch" + videos[key]._id}>
                                                <div key={key}  className="container">
                                                    <div className="thumbnail">
                                                        <img className="previmg" src=
                                                            {videos[key].coverURL}
                                                             alt="PreviewImg"
                                                        />
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div className="body">
                                                        <div className="body__img"></div>
                                                        <div className="body__txt">
                                                            <div className="title1">
                                                                <p>{videos[key].videoname}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="title2">
                                                                <p>{videos[key].channelName}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    ))}

                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }




export default SearchDisplay;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант раутинга по вашему примеру. Немного упростил код, но принцип такой. Добавил переход на фильтрованный список.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const linkStyle = {
  border: "1px solid black",
  padding: "1rem",
  margin: "1rem",
  display: "block",
};

const fakeServerData = [
  { id: "1", label: "Ocean1", description: "Ocean1-Description1" },
  { id: "2", label: "Ocean2", description: "Ocean2-Description2" },
  { id: "3", label: "Video1", description: "Video1-Description1" },
  { id: "4", label: "Video2", description: "Video2-Description2" },
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={SearchDisplay} />
      <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchResults} />
      <Route path="/search/:id" component={Video} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;

const SearchDisplay = ({ history }) => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");

  const searchButtonHandler = () => {
    const filteredData = fakeServerData.filter((item) =>
      item.label.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
    );

    history.push("/search", filteredData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      SearchDisplay
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setFilter(value)}
        value={filter}
      />
      <button onClick={searchButtonHandler}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const SearchResults = ({ location, history }) => {
  const data = location.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>SearchResults</h3>
      {data.map(({ id, label }) => (
        <Link key={id} to={`/search/${id}`} style={linkStyle}>
          Video: {label}
        </Link>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Go back</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Video = ({ match, history }) => {
  // здесь обычно загружаем данные с сервера по id
  const currentVideo = fakeServerData.find(({ id }) => id === match.params.id);
  const { id, label, description } = currentVideo;

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>This Video is {label}</h3>
      <h4>id: {id}</h4>
      <p>Description: {description}</p>
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Go back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: тут , мне кажется, не совсем то, это просто переход на видео, а у меня проблема именно с фильтрацией. Например есть два видео с названиями "океан" ,"глубокий океан" , и есть input поиска с кнопкой поиска. И если я хочу найти видео "океан", то я ввожу в input слово океан и жму кнопку- мне выводит условных два эти видео. Вот такое у меня не получается реализовать

Comment: этого не было в вопросе, я обновил код, теперь можно фильтровать.

Comment: Я вам крайне благодарен, вы очень помогаете, не сочтите совсем невежливым, а можно ли это реализовать с переходом на другую страницу, чтобы результаты поиска высвечивались уже в другом компоненте и были привязаны к условной кликабельной кнопки поиска?

Comment: ввели запрос нажали кнопку, перешли на отфильтрованный список. Потом раутинг   не нужен дальше? просто отфильтрованный список?

Comment: Это должно наподобие поиска в ютубе работать. Там выводится также страница с отфильтрованными по названию Видео

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил переход на фильтрованный список

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, очень помогли! Если вы не против, у меня сохранились предыдущие версии ваших кодов, там логика все же разная, могу их здесь выгрузить, вдруг кому-то пригодится

Comment: Пожалуйста, не знаю код одинаковый, админам может не понравиться. Отметь ответ как правильный, лайк поставить наверное не получится.

Comment: Константин, уже будет наглостью, но хочу снова обратиться к вам с вопросом, ниже в комментариях я изложил примерную проблему, с которой столкнулся

Answer (score 0):

Снова возникли вопросы, пытаюсь код внедрить в проект, на данный момент выдает ошибку [image: Ошибка]

Коды следующие: В компоненте Header, который подключен к App и в котором осуществляется поиск:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './Header.scss';
import { MyContext } from '../../MyContext'
import { FeedContext } from '../../Pages/Feed/FeedContext'
import SearchDisplay from '../../Pages/SearchDisplay/SearchDisplay';



    const SearchComp = ({ history }) => {
        const { videos1 } = useContext(FeedContext)
        console.log(videos1)

        const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");

        const searchButtonHandler = () => {
            const filteredData = videos1.filter((item) =>
            item.videoname.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
            );

            history.push("/searchDisplay", filteredData);
        };

        return (
            <div>
            SearchDisplay
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setFilter(value)}
                value={filter}
            />
            <button onClick={searchButtonHandler}>Search</button>
            </div>
        );
        };

    const Header = () => {

        return (
            <>
                <Navbar fixed="top">

                                <Navbar.Brand href="/" >
                                    <div className="LaT">
                                    </div>
                                </Navbar.Brand>
                                <Navbar.Collapse     id="responsive-navbar-nav">

                                <BrowserRouter>
                                <div className="search">
                                    <SearchComp/>
                                </div>
                                </BrowserRouter>


                                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </>
        )
    }
    export default Header;
```

Сама компонента SearchDisplay, где должен происходить вывод

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Row, Col,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import './SearchDisplay.scss';
import { MyContext } from '../../MyContext'
import Navigation from '../../layout/navigation/navigation';
import Header from '../../layout/header/Header';

const linkStyle = {
    border: "1px solid black",
    padding: "1rem",
    margin: "1rem",
    display: "block",
  };
// const CabinetContext = React.createContext()




const SearchDisplay = ({ location, history }) => {
    const data = location.state;

    let [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
    let [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const { isFetching } = useContext(MyContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/user/my/favorites')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result =>{
            // console.log(result)
            setVideos( result )
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            setError(isFetching, e );
        });
        console.log('!!!',videos);
    }, [])

    if (error) return <div>{`Error: ${error.message}`}</div>;

        if (isFetching) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        else
            return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <div  className="Max">

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={2}>
                            <Navigation key="navigation"/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <div className="Box">
                                <div className="VideoList">
                                <h3>SearchResults</h3>

                                {data.map(({ _id, videoname }) => (
                                    <Link key={_id} to={`/search/${_id}`} style={linkStyle}>
                                    Video: {videoname}
                                    </Link>
                                ))}

                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }




export default SearchDisplay;
```

Также в Header приходит массив из Видео, со страницы с общим списоком Роликов:
[image: значения массива]

Пока не могу понять, в чем проблема, а их определенно несколько

Comment: Здесь так не принято задавать доп.вопросы. Необходимо создать новый вопрос, а этот ответ удалить. Ссылку на новый вопрос можешь оставить в коментах моего ответа, я посмотрю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246204/Поиск-видео-по-названию ссылка на новое обсуждение по теме