# Поиск видео по названию

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Создавал компоненту поиска видео по названию, с переходом на новую страницу(по принципу ютуба)
Снова возникли вопросы, пытаюсь код внедрить в проект, на данный момент выдает ошибку [image: Ошибка]

Коды следующие: В компоненте Header, который подключен к App и в котором осуществляется поиск:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './Header.scss';
import { MyContext } from '../../MyContext'
import { FeedContext } from '../../Pages/Feed/FeedContext'
import SearchDisplay from '../../Pages/SearchDisplay/SearchDisplay';



    const SearchComp = ({ history }) => {
        const { videos1 } = useContext(FeedContext)
        console.log(videos1)

        const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");

        const searchButtonHandler = () => {
            const filteredData = videos1.filter((item) =>
            item.videoname.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
            );

            history.push("/searchDisplay", filteredData);
        };

        return (
            <div>
            SearchDisplay
            <input
                type="text"
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setFilter(value)}
                value={filter}
            />
            <button onClick={searchButtonHandler}>Search</button>
            </div>
        );
        };

    const Header = () => {

        return (
            <>
                <Navbar fixed="top">

                                <Navbar.Brand href="/" >
                                    <div className="LaT">
                                    </div>
                                </Navbar.Brand>
                                <Navbar.Collapse     id="responsive-navbar-nav">

                                <BrowserRouter>
                                <div className="search">
                                    <SearchComp/>
                                </div>
                                </BrowserRouter>


                                </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </>
        )
    }
    export default Header;
```

Сама компонента SearchDisplay, где должен происходить вывод

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Row, Col,} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import './SearchDisplay.scss';
import { MyContext } from '../../MyContext'
import Navigation from '../../layout/navigation/navigation';
import Header from '../../layout/header/Header';

const linkStyle = {
    border: "1px solid black",
    padding: "1rem",
    margin: "1rem",
    display: "block",
  };
// const CabinetContext = React.createContext()




const SearchDisplay = ({ location, history }) => {
    const data = location.state;

    let [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
    let [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const { isFetching } = useContext(MyContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/user/my/favorites')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result =>{
            // console.log(result)
            setVideos( result )
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            setError(isFetching, e );
        });
        console.log('!!!',videos);
    }, [])

    if (error) return <div>{`Error: ${error.message}`}</div>;

        if (isFetching) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        else
            return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <div  className="Max">

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={2}>
                            <Navigation key="navigation"/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <div className="Box">
                                <div className="VideoList">
                                <h3>SearchResults</h3>

                                {data.map(({ _id, videoname }) => (
                                    <Link key={_id} to={`/search/${_id}`} style={linkStyle}>
                                    Video: {videoname}
                                    </Link>
                                ))}

                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }




export default SearchDisplay;
```

Также в Header приходит массив из Видео, со страницы с общим списоком Роликов:
[image: значения массива]

Пока не могу понять, в чем проблема, а их определенно несколько

**UPDATE**

код App, где рендерится SearchDisplay

```
import React, { lazy, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';


import './App.scss';
import {MyContext} from './MyContext'
import Feed from './Pages/Feed/Feed';
import Cabinet from './Pages/Cabinet/Cabinet';
// import Downloads from './Pages/Downloads/Downloads';
import Watch from './Pages/Watch/Watch';
import Favorites from './Pages/Favorites/Favorites';'

import SearchDisplay from './Pages/SearchDisplay/SearchDisplay';

import Subs from './Pages/Subs/Subs';
import History from './Pages/History/History';
...



const App = () => {

const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false)
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(true)
const [videos, setVideos] = useState({});
let [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {

      fetch('/api/auth/isauthorized')
      .then(result => result=result.json())
      .then(result => {
          // console.log("result", result);

          if(result._id!==null){
            setIsAuthorized(!isAuthorized);
            setIsFetching(!isFetching);
            setUserData(userData= result);
            // console.log("userData", userData);
            
              // this.setState({isAuthorized: true, isFetching: true, userData: result});
          }else{
            setIsAuthorized(isAuthorized);
            setIsFetching(!isFetching);
              // this.setState({isAuthorized: false, isFetching: true})
          }
      })
      .then((result) => {
        // console.log("result", result);
          fetch('/api/videos/by/' + userData.nickname)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(response => {
              // console.log("response", response);
                setVideos(response)
                // (!isFetching)
              })

      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        setError(e);
        //!isFetching
    })
  }, [])

    if (error) return <div>{`Error: ${error.message}`}</div>; // ?????

    if (isFetching ) {
        return <img src={monkeyLoader} alt="Loading..." />
    }

  return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{
        isAuthorized, isFetching, userData, videos
      }} >
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
                <Route exact path="/cabinet" component={Cabinet} />
                {/* <Route exact path="/downloads" component={Downloads} /> */}

                <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>

                <Route exact path="/watch:videoId" component={Watch} />
                <Route exact path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />

                <Route exact path="/searchDisplay" component={SearchDisplay} />

                <Route exact path="/history" component={History} />
                <Route exact path="/subs" component={Subs} />

                <Route exact path="/downloadVideoPage" component={DownloadVideoPage} />

                <Route exact path="/successRegistration" component={SuccessRegistration} />
                {/* <Route exact path="/support" component={Support} /> */}

                  <Route exact path="/support"
                          render= {withSuspense(Support)}
                  />


                  <Route exact path="/logreg1" component={Logreg} />
                  <Redirect to="/" />

            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Можешь добавить код где рендерится SearchDisplay ?  В App.js?  <BrowserRouter> должен быть там а не в Header.

Comment: App добавил, я по-разному пробовал, видимо отправил код сюда, когда решил вставить Router в header